# SlidingTabLayout with subtabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-sliding

I would like to implement subtabs in SlidingTabLayout.

I searched a lot, but I don't have found anything like it.

Does anyone have a solution or a suggestion for implementing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a simple approach. You can associate you main tabs with viewpagers. Then, in those viewpagers you may add more slidingtablayouts in order to attain what you want to. I've got it working successfully. So nest the slidingtablayouts and you'll do fine. If you want some code, feel free to ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a simple example of sub tabs with slidingtab:
https://github.com/steinmetz/SubSlidingTabs